# CSS A::after link doesn't work on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I generate a button using CSS a::after 
In all browser the button is ok 
In all browser the link is ok except Safari

In other browser everything is ok, but in Safari the button is generated but is not possible to click on it, no cursor pointer and not click on safari.

Any idea?
here the code, you can test it on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ddDa4/

```
<a href="http://google.com">google.com</a>


a::before {

    content: "» Details";
    float: right;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.12em;
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #7CCA0D;
    padding: 7px 10px 9px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: -2px;

}
```

thanks

Comment: You're sure you don't have colon too many ?

Comment: Try `a:before`, should work.

Comment: Which version of Safari, and on which platform?

Comment: @adeneo: That's not one colon too many.

Comment: @BoltClock - I know it's now the preferred CSS3 way to do it, that's why I asked so nicely ?

Answer (score 1):

position:relative solves your problem

```
a::before {
    position:relative;
    content: "» Details";
    float: right;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.12em;
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #7CCA0D;
    padding: 7px 10px 9px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```